# Can one get sick from drinking too much home made Water Kefir?

Tags: food-safety, alcohol, fermentation

Using well water and some Odwalla orange juice..  What is the maximum amount that is safe for consumption daily?

Comment: Your question title doesn't at all match the question body. Which are you asking "Can I get sick" or "is my culture alive"?

Comment: This strikes me as the kind of thing you'd post on a forum to initiate a conversation - "Hey, I've just started making Water Kefir!"

Comment: This sounds like a health question, not a cooking question. Knowing **if** a normally-edible food is still safe and/or how to make it safe is the domain of food safety. Asking *how much* is safe is fundamentally about diet and nutrition, which is off-topic here. See the [tag wiki](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info) for more info on which questions are on topic.

Answer (score 2):

Like most fermented beverages made at home, water kefir is safe to drink as long as you take proper sanitation precautions. If mold is growing, don't drink it, throw it out, and sanitize your vessels. Learn to look for signs of mold.

Fermented beverages like kefir and kombucha can become quite acidic and leech minerals from their container. Store them in glass.

I doubt there is any safety hazard from drinking too much if it is properly prepared. I suppose if it's acidic enough and you drink too much you could get a stomach ache.